MongooseServerSelectionError: connect
I am deploying a full stack application on render. But I don't know why I am getting this
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:897:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:848:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { '0.0.0.0:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

error in the render logs. My database is also running fine but I don't know why my application is not running.
I have used this code for my mongodb connection.  `
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

Thankyou.
My page keeps crashing when I log in

If your database is hosted on Atlas, login to the Atlas dashboard and make sure your IP address is whitelisted there.

Thankyou soo much sir, Its work for me..
